# Stacking Subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

i would like to stack 2 subplots so that one of them is in front of the other one. In addition to that i would like to set the size of the subplot in the back a little bit bigger than the subplot in the front in order to see the edges. Here is an example how it should look.

[image]

For both subplots i need to use `ax = Subplot(fig,111)` and `fig.add_subplot(ax)` cause i want to implement a gridhelper in the subplots.

Is it possible to change the size of ax2 without changing ax1 so that ax2 in the background is slightly bigger than ax1 ?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you on the right track, although I am not sure how it influences your grid helper requirement:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x, y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1024), np.linspace(-5, 5, 1024)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1))  # lower_x, lower_y, width, height
ax.plot(x,y)
ax = fig.add_axes((0.2,0.2,.6,.6))
ax.plot(x,y)
```

source: [here](https://e2eml.school/matplotlib_framing.html)